Does this mean that there are no non trivial cycles in the Collatz Conjecture?
I am a grade 9 student who is fascinated with the Collatz Conjecture. I tried to 'prove' that the $4-2-1-4$ cycle is the only cycle that exists. I am aware that there is a huge chance that this is hugely flawed or already known, but I wanted to share my thoughts.
I started with a couple of basic ideas in mind:
1. A cycle must be at least 3 numbers, as two numbers can't cycle back and forth
2. I'll use $a$ to represent the largest number in the cycle, like the $4$ in the $4-2-1$ cycle
3. A loop must 'start' with an even number because the number before it must be odd. For example, $4-2-1$ 'ends' with an odd number because the only way to get back to the start is to use the odd number rule. If the 'last' number is odd then the 'first' number must be even.
That being said, here is how I thought of it:
$a = 3c + 1$
$b = 0.5a$
$c = 0.5b$

$a-1 = 3c$
$\frac{a-1}{3} = c$
$\frac{a-1}{3} = 0.5b$
$\frac{2(a-1)}{3} = b$
$\frac{2(a-1)}{3} = 0.5a$
$\frac{4(a-1)}{3} = a$
$\frac{4a - 4}{3} = a$
$4a - 4 = 3a$
$4a  = 3a +4$
$4a-3a = 4$
$a = 4$

If I understand this correctly, this indicates that 4 is the only number to 'start' a cycle, because otherwise there would be other solutions to this. Also, this is by no means a formal proof, just some ideas.
Apologies for the bad formatting, this is my first post.

As you correctly mention , such simple observations are of course no proof since we could have an extremely long cycle. In fact , we neither know whether there is a nontrivial cycle nor whether there is a trajectory diverging to $\infty$.

Concerning the cycles : It is known that a possible nontrivial cycle must be unimaginably long. A heuristic argument indicates that there is probably no diverging trajectory.

You've proved that 4-2-1 is the only cycle with exactly three numbers. This doesn't rule out longer cycles.

No. You can prove algebraically that any other cycle starts with 4k+3 other numbers fall below themselves quickly. Only numbers of form 4k+3 can loop or escape.

       
As @RoddyMacPhee has already said, what you've proven is that $4-2-1-4-2-... $ is the only $3$-step cycle.   
I think a more efficient notation (but in your style of reasoning) allows a more general formulation and then insight into the conditions for $3$,$4$,$N$-step cycles. I give this here just in case you might try it "for fun" :-)      
First, I always use the basic notation for the transformation from some odd integer $a$ to the next odd integer $b$ (or in more general formulae from $a_k$ to $a_{k+1}$) as
$$b = {3a+1 \over 2^A} $$
where in $A$ are counted all divisions by 2 which make $b$ an odd number again.
This gives for the $1$-step cycle on odd numbers your idea the form
$$ a = {3a+1 \over 2^A} $$ and then
$$ 2^A = {3a+1 \over a} \\
2^A = (3 + {1 \over a}) $$
and we recognize immediately, that the only integer number (and additionaly power of $2$) can occur if $a=1$. Then the rhs equals $4$ and the exponent $A=2$. Thus we have a solution plus we have that there can only be one (if we are in the positive numbers for $a$).

But what about of $2$-odd-step-cycles? 
We write
$$b = {3a+1 \over 2^A} \qquad a = {3b+1 \over 2^B} $$
We do the multiplication of the two involved elements $a,b$ and get
$$a \cdot b = {3a+1 \over 2^A}\cdot {3b+1 \over 2^B} $$
and reorder as before
$$ 2^{A+B} = (3+{1 \over a})\cdot (3+{1 \over b}) $$
Here we introduce two notations: $N=2$ for the numbers of odd-steps and $S=A+B$ for the number of even steps or, divisions by $2$.
Since we assume, that $1 \le a,b \le \infty$ we see limits for the rhs:
$$ \underset{\text{from } a,b=\infty}{\phantom{\frac10}(3+0)(3+0)} \le 2^S \le \underset{\text{from } a,b=1}{(3+\frac11)\cdot (3+\frac11)} 
$$
and we see that the space for solutions for $2^S$ is between $9=3^2$ and $16=2^4$ and no other integer solution is possible as for $a=b=1$ and $S=4$.

Analoguously you may try generalizations for $S$ and $N$ and can easily find lots of $N$ for which we cannot have an odd-step-cycle of length $N$. 
         
An even further developed scheme can be used to check the existence (or at least conditions on its smallest element) of odd-step-cycles of a wished length $N$, from where also a minimal $S$ (likely unique, but this is not yet proven) can be found.        
Assume we want to test an $N=7$ step cycle with elements $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ (or of course $a_1, \ldots , a_7$).
We do the ansatz
$$ 2^S = (3+{1 \over a})\cdot (3+{1 \over b}) \ldots (3+{1 \over g})$$
There must be an intermediate (likely irrational) value $\alpha$ between the minimum (we set the minimum value at $a$) and the the maximum value (not known yet, which of $b,c,d,e,f,g$ has the maximum value) such that as well
$$ 2^S = \left(3+{1 \over \alpha}\right)^N \qquad \text{assuming } a \le \alpha $$
We can reformulate:
$$2^{S/N} = \left(3+{1 \over \alpha}\right) \\
2^{S/N} -3 = {1 \over \alpha} \\
\alpha = { 1 \over 2^{S/N} -3}
$$
From $0 \lt 2^{S/N} -3 \le 1$ we can find in this case possible solutions $(N,S)=(7,12),(7,13),(7,14)$ and inserted
$$ \begin{array} {} S=12 &\to &\alpha = 3.5544... \\
   S=13 &\to &\alpha = 1.605... \\
   S=14 &\to &\alpha = 1.0 
 \end{array}
$$
Since we assume $a$ being the smallest element in the cycle, thus $a \le \alpha$ and also $a \in \{1,5,7,11,...\}$ (no element of the cycle can have the primefactor $3$) we see that the only possible solutions are with $a=1$. But we know already, that on $a=1$ starts the trivial cycles with $a=b=...=g=1$ and thus $S=2 \cdot N = 14$ and this is indeed the trivial cycle and that moreover no other solution exists.
This is a very simple tool to step into the discussion of "how large must $N$ become such that $a$ is larger then the largest number of empirically tested elements, say  $a \gt 2^{70}$".
